# Determine which button was pressed

Tags: unity, c#

I have 4 buttons, which on clicking,all of them does the same thing (each displays a different string read from an array to the button's text field). I want to have a single OnClick function to keep my code clean, instead of having 4 different functions for 4 different buttons. But I need to determine which button was pressed, How to do that inside OnClick Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-currentSelectedGameObject.html) defined in the `UnityEngine.EventSystems` namespace :

```
 public void OnClick()
 {        
     Debug.Log( UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name ) ;
 }
```